# Shipping SDL2 project in Ubuntu for deployment

Tags: c, sdl, project-management

I have created a SDL2 project in Ubuntu using C and the terminal as compiler. I want to ship the project in order to send it to my friends. Does anybody know how to achieve that without needing to install the library on the very computer it arrives?

Comment: Do all your friends also use linux?

Comment: Not all of them. It's a school project and we must build it on a Ubuntu OS

Comment: Making portable apps on linux can be tricky, and there's no single standard solution ([appimage](https://appimage.org/), [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/), [snap](https://snapcraft.io/), and what not). I'd suggest making a build for Windows instead, and those of the friends who use Ubuntu can run it under Wine.

Comment: Personally, installing `SDL2` on ubuntu is easy [enough]. Especially since you're collaborating with other [classmate] developers. However, what you may be looking for is a "container" system, such as `docker`, `kubernetes`, etc.